# Leaflet polygon precision loss on zoom out

Tags: leaflet, zooming, precision, polygon

I'm creating multipolygon using geojson data.
While zooming in/out the precision of the polygon fades, the corner points move.

Any suggestion how i can make the polygon more precise when zoomed out?

This is how my current code looks. I went through the documentation and tried multiple things including smoothFactor, but nothing seems to have a effect.

I'm kinda stuck now and need your help.

```js
  var map = L.map('map', {
      zoomControl: false,
      zoomSnap: 0.0,
      scrollWheelZoom: true,
      keyboard: false,
      dragging: false,
      boxZoom: false,
      doubleClickZoom: false,
      tap: false,
      touchZoom: false,
      maxNativeZoom: 1,
      animate: false,
      easeLinearity: 0
  });

  paths =
      [[[[6.858829796182704, 46.95251393022377],
          [6.858822143959083, 46.95252165923424],
          [6.858803353389316, 46.95251293626237],
          [6.858811005614312, 46.952505207253175],
          [6.858829796182704, 46.95251393022377]]],
          [[[6.858817924471068, 46.95249692043298],
          [6.858810272248277, 46.95250464944266],
          [6.858791481686369, 46.95249592646894],
          [6.858799133910535, 46.95248819746051],
          [6.858817924471068, 46.95249692043298]]],
          [[[6.858837595845731, 46.95250605229153],
          [6.8588299436243805, 46.952513781302564],
          [6.858811153056015, 46.95250505833199],
          [6.858818805278741, 46.95249732932224],
          [6.858837595845731, 46.95250605229153]]]]
  geojsonLayer = L.polygon(paths, {
      smoothFactor: 0.0,
      color: "grey",
      weight: 1,
      opacity: 1,
      fillColor: "white",
      fillOpacity: 1,
  })
  geojsonLayer.addTo(map);
  geojsonLayer.smoothFactor = 0.0
  console.log(geojsonLayer.getBounds())
  map.setZoom(24.851706204825632)
  console.log(map.getZoom())
  var latlng = L.latLng(6.858817924471068, 46.95249692043298);
  map.panTo(latlng)
  map.zoomSnap
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <style>

        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        html, body, #map {
            height: 1000px;
            width: 1000px;
            position: fixed;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }

    </style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="map"></div>

</body>

</html>
```